# access iCloud backup app data

Tags: ios, icloud, backup

How can I access the iCloud backup app data, i.e. the app data from my iPhone? E.g., I would like to make a local copy of it on my computer (without accessing the iPhone directly, i.e. really just the iCloud backup app data).

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's an interface to the iCloud backup data that will let you pull it down to a computer. An alternative, if you're after a local backup in addition to iCloud, is to plug your iPhone in and use iTunes to explicitly back up the device (right-click the iPhone in the left-hand pane and select `Back Up...`

I have iTunes set *not* to sync with my phone, as I normally backup to the cloud, but I'll occasionally do an explicit iTunes backup for redundancy's sake.

Comment: There must be an interface because otherwise the iPhone wouldn't be able to recover from the iCloud data. And if the iPhone is able to access the interface, I'm sure you could replicate the interface-access also on the PC. But I guess this interface is not public documented (well, actually, that was part of my question - if it maybe is). But it would be nice to have that reverse engineered otherwise.

Comment: Fair enough - my use of 'interface' was meant to refer to something available to an end user, which is the focus of Ask Different.

Comment: Is it possible to do this local backup via wi-fi ?

Comment: You can back up to iTunes via wifi, but I believe you have to [set up wifi syncing first](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203075); backups occur as part of the sync process.